# How to know count of hits for an Amazon API Gateway from API cache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an Amazon API gateway configured for one of my service.
Is there any easy way to keep a track of counts of hit for an API gateway, where I can keep count, hit count, miss count or Error Count?

Is there any API of AWS which I can hit to get the count for specified interval of time?

Answer (score 1):

The API cache is a CloudFront distribution, and cache hit rate is one of the  [extra-cost metrics available in CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/viewing-cloudfront-metrics.html#monitoring-console.distributions-additional).

Beware, however, that this metric is an aggregate of all requests. If you need to find hit rate on a per-path basis, you'll need to enable access logging and then analyze the results.

Comment: from access logging, it's tedious to find count of request for a end-point for a given interval of time, isn't it? Also I think the logs are not real time, they comes with some delay.
I need the data for every minute and also real time.

Comment: @user3393228 - Well, pending someone who knows about an undocumented feature, you have to use what you've got. And tbh, I question the need to know real-time hit rate. What is your actual use case?

Comment: I need to publish the real-time visit event data on a Dashboard. S

Comment: And what is that event data used for? Is a per-URL cache miss rate necessary? Is "real time" a hard requirement, and why? Depending on the answers to those questions, you may not be able to use AWS managed services at all. I suggest talking to whoever set out the requirements, to find the implementation that satisfies the _business_ use case.